# Doing extra initialisations on a MFC Dialog in Visual Studio C++ 2008 Pro

Tags: c++, mfc

How do I make extra initializations on a modal dialog before calling DoModal(); ?

The whole application is created using VS wizards.
I have a main Dialog (the one that is created automatically when I select new MFC Application in Visual Studio 2008 Professional). 
When I click a button on this dialog I want to open another dialog and set a CString value into a CEdit control.

my code:

```
...
void MainDlg::OnClickedButtonX(){
   SecondDialogClass Dlg2;
   Dlg2.asocVar2Cedit.SetWindowTextW(L"my text");
   Dlg2.DoModal();
}
//asocVar2Cedit is the associeted control variable to the 
//CEdit control on the second Dialog (Right Click > Add Variable..  in VSC++)
...
```

this code generates at runtime a "Debug Assertion" error in winocc...

Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `OnInitDialog` (`WM_INITDIALOG`) handler to your CDialog-derived class and have it initialise itself.

Comment: actually this could help.. but I can't understand what exactly did you meant.. what is the method prototype ? how do I have it to initialise itself ?